# Wordpress Taxonomy Terms - foreach(): not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, custom-taxonomy

I want to create a link for each term in a custom Wordpress taxonomy.

I don't get why this isn't working. A `var_dump($artwork_media)` returns the full array but putting `var_dump($artwork_medium)` within the foreach loop returns only the first item. Also the HTML doesn't get outputted at all.

```
<?php $artwork_media = get_terms( 'artwork_media' , array('taxonomy' => 'artwork_media', 'hide_empty' => 0) ); ?>

<div class="link-block">
  <ul class="artwork-list row">

  <?php foreach( $artwork_media as $artwork_medium ): ?>
    <a href="/artwork/<?php echo $artwork_medium['slug']; ?>/" class="span3"><li><?php echo $artwork_medium['name']; ?></li></a>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised when checking my error_log that the $artwork_media array contains objects, not arrays. Solution is to use  `$artwork_medium->slug` and  `$artwork_medium->name`